# How to get the style of a custom cell class, to instantiate the custom cell programatically

Tags: swift

I would like to instantiate a custom table view cell programmatically as the way I have created it has the ideal UI for my situation

I've tried many different ways to get the style of my custom cell class when instantiating my cell programmatically but none of them were actually giving it the properties of my custom cell, the properties being a few custom labels and a stepper I was using to affect the value of one of the labels text

```
let cell = StepperTableViewCell(style: StepperTableViewCell.CellStyle.default, 
reuseIdentifier: "cellID")
```

I expect it to return a cell that is my custom cell but it always fails when I use any of the properties of my custom cell, saying

> MaverickPantry[33017:447102] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while
>   implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Could you please show where you set the cell ‘s reuseIdentifier?

Comment: I set the cell's reuse identifier when I instantiated it, let cell = StepperTableViewCell(style: StepperTableViewCell.CellStyle.default, 
reuseIdentifier: "cellID"), the reuse identifier is the string "cellID"

Comment: The cell itself is not an optional value, so maybe the problem happens in the custom cell class definition. I suppose that this issue happens when declaration .CellStyle.default. Please make sure that there is a value for .default.